# To see JPG file from API gateway and Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created some code on lambda using node.

```
const fs= require('fs');
const axios= require('axios');

exports.handler= async (event, context, callback) => {

  const imageBase64= await axios.get(
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Prunus_flower.jpg',
    {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}
    ).toString('base64');

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' },
    body: imageBase64,
    isBase64Encoded: true,
    }
}
```

I also set up API gateway.

Binary Media Types is
`image/*`

Then, when I access API gateway.
I encountered bellow error.

[image]

https://p9knlxmx62.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/img/

I'm not sure how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `imageBase64` is not a valid image Base64 string.

To get a image file form url and transfer to base64 string with `axios`, you can see my code:

```
...
const response = await axios.get(
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Prunus_flower.jpg',
  { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
);
const imageBase64 = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You've to call callback.

2) Result of axios call is object where image is in `.data`

So overall handler code:

```
exports.handler= async (event, context, callback) => {

  const imageBody = await axios.get(
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Prunus_flower.jpg',
    {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}
  );

  callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' },
      body: imageBody.data.toString('base64'),
      isBase64Encoded: true,
    }
  );
}
```